# Sequence of events when a hardware is connected to Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Can anybody tell me sequence of common events when a hardware (Let's say USB stick or Keyboard) is connected to a machine running Linux kernel ? Actually i am new to Device Driver field and i want to know what are the common events when a hardware is connected. Any link or resource will be helpful.

Comment: http://makelinux.com/ldd3/

Comment: Go through this link http://janaxelson.com/usbcenum.htm w.r.t usb enumeration.